# Google Analytics API - data discrepancy between API and dashboard for various products,

Tags: google-analytics-api

we are facing a serious issue of data discrepancy between API response and Google Analytics dashboard page views count for various products, interestingly graph is coming same, we are using below mentioned API endpoint to fetch page views:

**API end point:**

> https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga

**Request:**

```
{
    start-date:2017-02-01
    end-date:2017-02-28
    ids:ga:108134524
    metrics:ga:pageviews
    dimensions:ga:hostname
    sort:-ga:pageviews
    filters:ga:hostname!=/;ga:dimension10==56b261282cbcbe7073adb603
    output:dataTable
    _src:embed-api:v1
}
```

**response**

```
enter code here

{     
     "kind":"analytics#gaData",
     "id":"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?    ids=ga:108134524&dimensions=ga:hostname&metrics=ga:pageviews&sort=-ga:pageviews&filters=ga:hostname!%3D/;ga:dimension10%3D%3D56b261282cbcbe7073adb603&start-date=2017-02-01&end-date=2017-02-28",
     "query":{
        "start-date":"2017-02-01","end-date":"2017-02-28",
        "ids":"ga:108134524",
        "dimensions":"ga:hostname",
        "metrics":["ga:pageviews"],
        "sort":["-ga:pageviews"],
        "filters":"ga:hostname!=/;ga:dimension10==56b261282cbcbe7073adb603",
        "start-index":1,"max-results":1000},
        "itemsPerPage":1000,
        "totalResults":1,
        "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:108134524&dimensions=ga:hostname&metrics=ga:pageviews&sort=-ga:pageviews&filters=ga:hostname!%3D/;ga:dimension10%3D%3D56b261282cbcbe7073adb603&start-date=2017-02-01&end-date=2017-02-28",
        "profileInfo":{
            "profileId":"108134524",
            "accountId":"67358318",
            "webPropertyId":"UA-67358318-1",
            "internalWebPropertyId":"103966122",
            "profileName":"All Web Site Data",
            "tableId":"ga:108134524"
        },
        "containsSampledData":true,
        "sampleSize":"250252",
        "sampleSpace":"2964571",
        "columnHeaders":[{
            "name":"ga:hostname",
            "columnType":"DIMENSION",
            "dataType":"STRING"
         },{
            "name":"ga:pageviews",
            "columnType":"METRIC",
            "dataType":"INTEGER"
         }],
         "totalsForAllResults":{"ga:pageviews":"12"},
         "dataTable":{
             "cols":[{
                 "id":"ga:hostname",
                 "label":"ga:hostname",
                 "type":"string"
             },
             {
                 "id":"ga:pageviews",
                 "label":"ga:pageviews",
                 "type":"number"
             }],
             "rows":[{
                 "c":[{"v":"www.australiatourism.travel"},
                 {"v":"12"}]}
             ]}
     }
```

**Response from Google API's**

[image: Response we are getting on our page using API's]

**Response visible on GA**

[image: Response on GA Analytics Page using same parameters]

interesting fact we are getting same graph, but don't know why we are getting different page views with API endpoint and Google Analytics dashboard for similar dates, please help us in resolving the same?

Regards,
Nakul

Comment: Can you please show the differences you are seeing.   Give data please :)

Comment: sure I have mentioned below part of the json response for pageviews :
`code` {
    "dataTable":{
        "cols":[{"id":"ga:hostname","label":"ga:hostname","type":"string"},{"id":"ga:pageviews","label":"ga:pageviews","type":"number"}],
        "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"www.australiatourism.travel"},{"v":"12"}]}]
    }
}

Comment: and on Google Analytics Dashboard we are getting 24

Comment: @google-api-support Team, please update and provide some solution

Comment: This is StackOverflow we are not Google there is little chance anyone from Google will respond.

Comment: That's not the same request. Your request is date and pageviews the response you just gave me is hostname and pageviews.  Use this take a screen shot of what you put In and the response then screen shot the website where you say the numbers are different https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: Hi Dalm thanks for the response, I have updated request and response from API's and added screen shots for Stats visible on our website and GA, please help in resolving we are fetching five different parameters :

`code`
1. 
metrics:ga:pageviews
dimensions:ga:date

2. 
metrics:ga:pageviews
dimensions:ga:region

3. 
metrics:ga:pageviews
dimensions:ga:country

4. 
metrics:ga:pageviews
dimensions:ga:hostname

5. 
metrics:ga:pageviews
dimensions:ga:hostname

Comment: On the ga website create a custom dashboard and request only the dimension and metric you are sending to the API.   You cant compare it unless you are preforming the exact same request.